# Received Pronunciation and ambiguity (users vs uses)

Tags: pronunciation, rhoticity, received-pronunciation

Let us consider the following two sentences:

> These **users** of our app allowed us to find a few new **uses** for it.

and

> These **uses** of our app allowed us to find a few new **users** for it.

Both of them are syntactically correct, but have opposite meaning.

However, as far as I understand, in Received Pronunciation both **users** and **uses** should sound the same.

How could these two sentences be distinguished between each other when spoken by a Received Pronunciation speaker?

Comment: "in Received Pronunciation both users and uses should sound the same" that is totally incorrect.

Comment: Users and uses are not pronounced the same.

Comment: Even if they were pronounced the same, we'd do what we do for all ambiguities: we'd reword, or explain, or spell, or it'd become the punchline of a joke. "You can't put too much water into a nuclear reactor"

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation) brings into question the whole concept of Received Pronunciation: 'Received Pronunciation (RP) is the accent of Standard English in the United Kingdom and is defined in the Concise Oxford English Dictionary as "the standard accent of English as spoken in the south of England", although it can be heard from native speakers throughout England and Wales. Peter Trudgill estimated in 1974 that 3% of people in Britain were RP speakers, but this rough estimate has been questioned by the phonetician J. Windsor Lewis.'

Answer (score 9):

The noun *user* is pronounced /ju:zə/ in RP. Notice that unless it is followed by a vowel, there is no /r/ in this word.

The verb *use* is pronounced /ju:z/.

However, the **noun** *use* is pronounced /ju:s/. Notice that unlike the noun *user* the noun *use* has an /s/ and not a /z/.

The words *users*, *uses* (verb) and *uses* (noun) are all very similar in English. But none of the three are homophones with either of the other two.

The noun *user* has a schwa at the end and so the plural, *users*, ends with /əz/. Like the other two words it has no /r/, but is different from them in that it has a schwa.

The verb *uses* has a regular third person ending. Because the base of the verb ends in a sibilant—in this case /z/—we use an /ɪz/ suffix here. So this word is /ju:zɪz/. This is distinguished from the noun *user* by having a KIT vowel instead of a schwa before the final /z/.

The noun *uses* has a plural suffix, which follows exactly the same rule as the third person singular suffix described above. The base word ends in a sibilant, and therefore the suffix /ɪz/ is applied. However, the sibilant which triggers the use of the /ɪz/ in this case is not /z/ but /s/.  So this word is distinguished from the noun *uses* by virtue of having a KIT vowel instead of a schwa. However, it is also easily distinguishable from both of the other  two words by having an /s/ at the end of the first syllable instead of a /z/.

The transcriptions for these words are:

- /ju:zəz/ (users)
- /ju:zɪz/ (uses - verb)
- /ju:sɪz/ (uses - noun)

Notice that the first two words here are distinguishable in RP because RP has not seen a merger of the KIT and schwa vowels, unlike several other world Englishes.

Comment: Are you sure that RP uses a KIT vowel here? In my personal idiolect (and how I hear the RP version in my head), this is an /ɨ/, not an /ɪ/. A word like _lazies_ has the KIT vowel, but not _uses_. Has RP really undergone a /ɪ ~ ɨ/ merger and I just haven't noticed? (Edit: Only just read StoneyB’s answer now. What he said.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yep, 100%. Incidentally,  Stoney also uses KIT and not FLEECE there, doesn't he?

Comment: No, he uses /ᵻ/, which is the more accurate way of writing what I wrote as /i̵/ above (couldn’t be bothered figuring out how to get an ᵻ on my phone). I’m not talking about the FLEECE vowel, but the reduced near-close central vowel (as opposed to KIT, which is near-close near-front). At least I have a possible four-way distinction in final, unstressed syllables here: _lasers_ /ˈleɪzəz/; _lazes_ /ˈleɪzᵻz/; _lazies_ /ˈleɪzɪs/; and, for lack of an exact minimal tetrad, _(analys)es_ /əˈnalᵻsi(ː)z/. I thought RP was the same; must listen closer to someone speaking it some time to check.

Comment: Hm. Looking at Wikipedia’s [IPA chart for English dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects), it looks like Welsh English is the only dialect traditionally attributed with a four-way split, and I’m fairly sure I don’t speak Welsh English…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet /ɨ/ is not generally used for RP at all, as it is generally used for vowels in accents in which there is a weak vowel merger. In RP, in contrast, there is still a clear distinction between weak KIT and schwa famously giving rise to a distinction between the minimal pair *Rosa's* and *roses* (though there is free variation between the two in some other contexts). RP exhibits a three way split for most speakers between *lasers* (schwa), *lazies* (FLEECE for most younger speakers - but KIT for some older, hence the need for the unsatisfactory 'HAPPY vowel'), and *lases* (KIT).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's my understanding of /ɨ/ anyhow. Note that Stoney gives '/ɪ/ or /ᵻ/', but if you follow his link he explains that where RP transcriptions use KIT to represent a weak vowel for  Gen Am ones tend to use /ᵻ/.

Comment: Hm. I guess I’ve just never noticed these unstressed vowels very particularly in RP speakers, then. I had always just assumed that there was no vowel merger in RP, but I guess there is. Pronouncing _lazies_ with the FLEECE vowel sounds natural and normal enough to me, though I’d have KIT myself; but pronouncing _lazes/lases/roses_ with an undreduced KIT sounds distinctly odd in my head—though I daresay, since I’ve never noticed it, that I don’t find it jarring if I hear it in natural speech.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh, I think I wasn't very clear there. There's free variation between KIT and schwa in words like *expect* (first syllable) where many speakers use KIT but some speakers use schwa. But not in words like *roses* and *Rosa's* where the two are distinct. But notice that in words like *expect*  different speakers have different phonemes in the word. So you're right that there *is* no weak vowel merger (KIT/schwa) in RP. The reason that I keep talking about *weak* KIT is not because the quality of the vowel is different when it is weak ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ... but because, of course, there is no merger of stressed KIT and schwa in most Englishes. (I don't know if that's clearer or more confusing! Er, I hope it's the former ....)

Comment: _Expect_ with schwa? That sounds… New Zealand-ish to me. I’d expect (!) variation between KIT and LET there, not between KIT and schwa. I wasn’t talking about the KIT/schwa merger, though, but about the KIT/ROSES merger. If I understand you correctly, RP does have that, since you say _lases_ has the KIT vowel. As I understand /ᵻ/, it’s a phoneme whose lexical set annoyingly doesn’t have a name (I call it ROSES), and whose pronunciation varies between a distinct [ɪ̈ ~ ɨ], a merger with KIT, and a merger with schwa. I have a distinct vowel for it, RP apparently not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think RP speakers almost universally have KIT in such plural suffixes/3rd person endings/possessives e.g. in *roses*. So, for such speakers it isn't really a merger as such. It's the same phoneme!

Comment: Well yes—but that’s exactly what lexical sets are all about. For speakers of dialects that pronounce _Rosa’s_ and _roses_ the same, those two have the same phoneme as well. It’s only cross-dialectally that lexical sets and their archiphonemes make sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, quite so.

Answer (score 6):

They are not pronounced the same, even in non-rhotic dialects like RP.

The noun *use* is pronounced with /s/, the verb *use* is pronounced with /z/:

> noun: /jus/, verb: /juz/

When these words are inflected with the *-s* affix many dictionaries represent the affix vowel with the 'schwa', /-əz/. However, the vowel actually used is somewhat higher; it may be represented with /ɪ/ or /ᵻ/. (See my answer to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/3446/32).)

> plural noun: /jusᵻz/, 3sg verb: /juzᵻz/

The noun *user*, derived from the verb, employs the verb's /z/; and the *-er* affix *does* employ a mid-central vowel, the schwa. In non-rhotic dialects, where the /R/ phoneme is deleted, this yields:

> /juzəz/.

---

*just for lagniappe:*
Very careful speakers, like classically-trained actors and singers, may pronounce the unstressed *-s* affix with an unreduced vowel, /ɛz/; and they may lower the schwa in the unstressed *-er* affix to something in the neighbourhood of /ɑ/. But nobody cares, or even notices, except other classically-trained actors and singers.

Answer (score 2):

No, *uses* and *users* are pronounced differently in RP.

> uses   /juzɪz/
>
> users  /juzəz/

Comment: This would seem to be the only correct or full answer here.

Comment: @Fattie: It's not correct – the noun *uses*, which is the word the OP is asking about, is pronounced /jusɪz/.

Comment: I may misunderstand something.  "uses" (noun) and "users" and "uses" (verb) have three different pronunciations.  In RP, and all dialects I know of.  It's a non-question, just a mistake by the OP.